# Using WireframeHelper with Loaded Objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

In my Three JS application, I downloaded some JSON files for objects from [clara.io](http://clara.io). I load them into the an object variable with `THREE.ObjectLoader`. I add it to the scene and everything works fine.

However, when I try to display the wireframe of the object with `THREE.WireframeHelper`, I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined`

Apparently, the geometry of the object is undefined.

So the question is: do custom shapes loaded in this manner always have empty geometries? If no, how can I obtain an object with it's geometry "intact"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loaded object likely has child objects and child meshes.

In your loader callback, use this pattern:

```
object.traverse( function( child ) {

    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

        var wh = new THREE.WireframeHelper( child, 0xffffff );
        scene.add( wh );

    }

} );
```

three.js r.73